# Load page in a tab with ZK

Tags: java, zk, tabpanel, zk-grid

I have this code in ZK, with a menu to navigate:

```
<zk apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
    viewModel="@id('vm') @init('menu')">
    <tabbox width="100%" sclass="nav_tabs">
        <tabs id="tabs">
            <tab label="Admin" onSelect="updateCategory(self.label)"/>
            <tab label="User" onSelect="updateCategory(self.label)"/>
        </tabs>
        <tabpanels>
            <tabpanel>
                <toolbar hflex="true">
                    <toolbarbutton label="CreateUser" onClick="@Command('load',label=self.label)" />
                    <toolbarbutton label="CreateMno" onClick="@Command('load',label=self.label)" />
                </toolbar>
            </tabpanel>
            <tabpanel>
                <toolbar hflex="true">
                    <toolbarbutton label="LoadData" onClick="@Command('load',label=self.label)" />
                    <toolbarbutton label="DownloadData" onClick="@Command('load',label=self.label)" />
                </toolbar>
            </tabpanel>
        </tabpanels>
    </tabbox>
    <separator height="30px"></separator>
    <zscript><![CDATA[
    void updateCategory(String category) {
        current_category.setValue(category);
        current_subpage.setValue("Index");
    }
]]></zscript>
    <hlayout>
        <label id="current_category" sclass="nav_text nav_category" onClick="@command('submit')">Our Product</label>
        <label sclass="nav_text">-</label>
        <label id="current_subpage" sclass="nav_text">Index</label>
    </hlayout>

</zk>
```

Then i have two roles Admin, and User, and i need load the pages of each user, and i am trying that when a user click in the toolbarbutton, for example CreateUser, then call a method that load in the space of my toolbar button the page, but i do not how can i do it.

Something like:

http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/tabbox/navigation_tabs

but i not need a string in Our product -> Product 1 - > Our Product-Product 1, i need load a page, and i am calling the page with the same name to the label.

And a page from a java class

Somebody can help me?

Comment: I think you are looking for ``Executions.getCurrent().createComponents(...)`` to instantiate ZUL-Files at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following to your `tabpanel`:

```xml
<include id="includeID" mode="instant" src="page.zul" />
```

Later on, you may load another page by adding the following to a `zscript`:

```java
includeID.setSrc("another_page.zul");
```